# Restore default privileges in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, privileges

Is there a way to restore default privileges on a table in PostgreSQL?

After creating a table, if i launch `\z` in *psql* i see this:

```
 Schema |    Name     |   Type   |     Access privileges     | Column access privileges
--------+-------------+----------+---------------------------+-------------------------
 public | example     | table    |                           |
```

phpPgAdmin, also, says that the privileges for the table **example** are the default ones.
If I edit these privileges, I would like to be able to revert my changes. Is this possible?
So far I tried with `REVOKE ALL`, which actually displays an empty *Access privileges* field when launching `\z`, but obviously doesn't work because it removes every privilege even from the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a direct way to do this.

The closest thing you can do is to do this and then grant ALL to the owner (you can look up the owner in `pg_class`).

One problem with doing it in this way is that default permissions could be set differently to that and that doing it purely in the backend requires using `DO` with a plpgsql statement.  Worse, since `GRANT` is not a planned statement, you cannot parameterize it, meaning you have to do string interpolation.